# Issue with UIActivityViewController iOS6

Tags: ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController to show the sharing sheet for the devices with iOS6, but the issue is that Until I am logged in to facebook, twitter in Settings, Facebook and twitter options will not be display while sharing?

Is there any possibility to display these icons as well even though user has not given his/her account credentials in Settings? Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible... If Facebook is not set up in Settings > Facebook, then the UIActivityViewController will not show Facebook as an option to share.

Answer (score 0):

As @amau96 said, it's not possible with `UIActivityViewController`.

But you can achieve same function via `SLComposeViewController`.

I created a forked project [OWActivityViewController](https://github.com/brantyoung/OWActivityViewController) that implement the same function as Apple's built-in **Photos** app's share action sheet through `SLComposeViewController`.

[OWActivityViewController](https://github.com/brantyoung/OWActivityViewController) compatible with iOS 5, hope this could help you somehow.